# apache rewrite for certain urls to be http instead of https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Further to an earlier question I had where I needed to rewrite urls such as

```
http://example.com/index.php?cPath=371_1659_1660&main_page=products_categories
```

to

```
http://example.com/index.php?cPath=371_1659_1660
```

I used this to fix it

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.)(^|&)main_page=products_categories(.)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [R=301,L]
```

I've also discovered that I also have the same urls as https so

```
https://example.com/index.php?cPath=371_1659_1660&main_page=products_categories
```

and

```
http://example.com/index.php?cPath=371_1659_1660&main_page=products_categories
```

are giving me duplicate page penalties

Is it possible to modify my rewrite rule so that it also redirects to the http page at the same time as removing the

```
&main_page=products_categories
```

suffix so that

```
https://example.com/index.php?cPath=371_1659_1660&main_page=products_categories
```

would become

```
http://example.com/index.php?cPath=371_1659_1660
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is clear and concise with examples of what's required and what I've done so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this question was unfairly down voted.

You can use this single rule to redirect both URLs to `http://...`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)main_page=products_categories(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(cPath=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you